# How to get an affect for balloon bursting in XNA?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I am a noob in XNA. I want to create an effect which shows a balloon bursting?

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 2D or 3D? What did you try so far?

Comment: 2D. I have no idea how to start. Need a kick to shatter my mindblock. I come from a Windows/Web background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have a one-frame image showing a bursting balloon. It doesn't even have to be great quality. See this [example](http://www.hsharma.com/_assets/tutorials/thumbs/balloonShooterFlashPunk/balloonShooterFlashPunk_ep2_thumb.jpg):

[image]

Animators can get away with a lot when it's something that appears very briefly. You'd be surprised how well this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cong. I checked the tutorials and I feel I am good to go!

Comment: http://www.hsharma.com/tutorials/balloon-shooter-game-in-flashpunk-episode-3-more-interactivity/